# Make a NodeJS server auto-detect a connected device through USB

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, usb

I did a web interface for a colorimeter using a NodeJS server which reads USB serial inputs using the **serialport npm library** and sends that info to a local web page. The colorimeter is basically a circuit using a microcontroller which is **connected to my PC through USB**, using an intermediate USB module.

The web page has state messages like: **"Device Detected"** (if the page is started with the device already inserted in the USB), **"Device Disconnected"** (if I pull out the device from the USB). The message updates perfectly for scenarios like pulling out the device from the USB port but I can't make it autodetect when inserting it back in the USB, without doing a browser page refresh.

Is there any workaround for making the Node server **detect automatically when the USB device is inserted** in the PC and update the state message?

Server code: https://codepen.io/grazvan/pen/wdLGPZ?editors=0010#0
Currently, I am doing it on Linux that's why the `boardPort = '/dev/ttyACM0';`. I am open for solutions in Windows or another programming language too.

Answer (score 2):

maybe try `node-usb`. on https://github.com/tessel/node-usb see *UsbDetection*:

```
   usb.on('attach', function(device) { ... });
```

> Attaches a callback to plugging in a device.

```
   usb.on('detach', function(device) { ... });
```

> Attaches a callback to unplugging a device.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that I wanted to implement a server which can connect to any type of serial port, not only USB (as the node-USB library does), I successfully implemented an auto-detection feature which listens and knows when the concerned device is connected.

```
let boardPort = '';
let boardKeywordIdentifier = 'Arduino'; //my device identifier
let checkingTimeInterval = 1000;
let waitForUsb = setInterval(getBoardPortName, checkingTimeInterval);

function getBoardPortName() {

    SerialPort.list(function(err,ports) {
        ports.forEach(function(port){

            if(port.manufacturer.includes(boardKeywordIdentifier)) {
                boardPort = port.comName;
            }

        })
    });

    if(boardPort != '') {
        clearInterval(waitForUsb);
        listenToTheBoard(boardPort); //function to be executed when board is connected
    }

}
```